# How to add a cell with Button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, uibarbuttonitem

How would this work in this case? I created a NSMutabeArray *dataSource; in my .h file, but getting a bunch of errors:

"RootViewController.m: error: Semantic Issue: Property 'dataSource' not found on object of type 'RootViewController *'"

RootViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
NSMutableArray *dataSource;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *dataSource;
- (IBAction)addButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

RootViewController.m

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize dataSource;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.dataSource = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
//adds right bar button.
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=addButton;
[addButton release];

}

-(void)addButton:(id)sender{
[self.dataSource addObject:@"New Item"];
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.dataSource count] inSection:0];
[self.dataSource insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some memory-guru will no doubt be able to tell you why @synthesize and mutable arrays and dictionaries (and sets, presumably) do not play well together. All I know is, initialize your mutable array explicitly and all will be well:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dataSource = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];

    //adds right bar button.
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=addButton;
    [addButton release];
}
```

And, of course, release it in the dealloc.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have not created property in .h file and you have used datasource variable with self.
please replace self.dataSource with dataSource or create property for it.

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *dataSource;
```

and synthesize in .m file

```
@synthesize dataSource;
```

Comment: Still get errors. I am using a tableview template, and using a group table view table. Basically I just want to tap the "+" button on the right navbar and add a cell. I had to add a button with code since you can't change the RootViewController.xib other than the IB option for the table. Maybe this clears things up more, thanks for your quick answer, but it doesn't work. Perhaps the info I gave will help more.

Comment: Your original question is very different from your comment here... you might want to edit your question to clarify. Are you still getting the same error that you listed in your question?

Comment: My question is How do I add a cell with button. That's what I'm trying to do...but since I can't add a nav button through IB to the RootViewController.xib, I had to add that with code. So just trying to figure out how to get the button I added from code to add a cell to the group table list.

Comment: I updated the code above, this is the error im getting: RootViewController.m:28: warning: 'NSMutableArray' may not respond to '-insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:' I also deleted the self.navaigationitem.rightbarbuttonitem.action =   that got rid of some more errors, but I cant connect the "Addbutton" action in IB, how would I also do this in code? Thank you!